# Pass data to controller and assign result to Model MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

i have a little problem with MVC C#. I dont know how i can pass data from view to controller, do something, after that send array to the same view and assing to List property of Model.

Example:

```
public class List1 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalValue { get; set;}
    public List<Elements> Details { get; set;}
}
public class Elements {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view where I create "heading" by selecting DateFrom, DateTo and typing TotalValue. After that I want to show modal where the periods will appear base on selecting data to creating a "elements".
Example: If to DateFrom choose today's date (28.06.2018) and to DateTo choose 31.08.2018, in modal i want to show three period, where i can enter the value assigned to the periods. 
First: 28.06.2018 - 30.06.2018, 
Second: 1.07.2018 - 31.07.2018, 
Third: 1.08.2018 - 31.08.2018.
After assigning values to periods, modal will close and i can save "heading" with elements (periods) to database.

For now, i do action after click button, where set periods as above. Now, I dont know how to show this period on modal and after all of this action assigned to Model property "Details"...

I hope that somebody understand me and will help!

Somethink like that:
[picture shows how i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZozx.png)

Comment: The name attribute of an HTML element is what is used to determine what elements are bound to what part of a Model, so if you are dynamically creating these Elements to be passed back to an ActionResult method you would do seomthing like <input name="Details[0].Name", <input name="Details[0].Value" etc...

Comment: Ok, tell me now what i have to return from ActionResult after setting periods? Now, I try return a List<Elements> but i Don't know how to assign it to Model property...

Comment: You need to use Model binding in your View, so with Razor syntax it would be something like Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Details[0].Name, new { @ id = "txtName0", @ class = "form-control" })

Comment: Okey, but when I open CreateView, my Details list is empty. After selecting DateFrom, DateTo and click button, Details List should be filled in three periods. When click button, now using $.post I execute a ActionResult method. I dont understand how send back this list from method to CreateView...

Comment: you have to pass your Model to the View in your CreateView Action, so something like return View("CreateView", myModelObject);